# Is it possible to restore my device to pre-factory reset for saved logins?

Tags: factory-reset

Basically, I have reset my phone after an absolute nightmare of forgetting my pattern.

In other to sign back into my Google account, it wants to send a notification to my S23 - however naturally this doesn't do anything after the reset.

Is it possible therefore to:

1. Work out what my previous device ID was before the reset? I still have websites saying I'm still signed in on the 'old phone', but I don't think it's possible to grab any more detailed information and sadly, I made no backups of the phone
2. If A is possible, can I spoof my device ID in order for apps like Google and Facebook to send a notification to my device?

Unfortunately, the recovery process for each account has failed. Google won't offer me a reset as I'm still allegedly signed in somewhere...

Comment: You should remove the device form your account https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/3067630?sjid=15906456687386033949-EU#remove If you can not login on the web portal because of the device reset you need to recover your account https://accounts.google.com/signin/recovery